# Does sigma-subadditive automatically imply sigma-additive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Since the condition for a finite-additive-measure to be sigma-additive is the sub additivity and almost all measure are at least finite additive, is there any difference between sigma-subadditivity and sigma-additity for a measure.

Thanks!

Comment: $\mu(S) = 1$ if $S\ne\emptyset$ and $=0$ otherwise is subadditive, but surely not additive, finitely or infinitely.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you for your answer!